# This JavaScript code is not working. Have I got the syntax wrong or is it something else?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This code is not working as I would have liked it to, but I am not sure of the problem.

**Code:**

```
<body>
  var randNumForQuote = Math.floor((Math.random() * 11));

  if (randNumForQuote == 0) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello";
  } else if (randNumForQuote == 1) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello1";
  } else if (randNumForQuote == 2) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello2";
  } else if (randNumForQuote == 3) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello3";
  } else if (randNumForQuote == 4) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello4";
  } else if (randNumForQuote == 5) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello5";
  } else if (randNumForQuote == 6) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello6";
  } else if (randNumForQuote == 7) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello7";
  } else if (randNumForQuote == 8) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello8";
  } else if (randNumForQuote == 9) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello9";
  } else if (randNumForQuote == 10) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello10";
  }

  <div id="quoteDiv"></div>
</body>
```

I have limited experience in JavaScript, so do not understand the problem too well.

I am expecting the div to say one of the outputs (eg. `Hello, Hello1, Hello2, etc.`)

Comment: You forgot to tell us what you are expecting.. This code is working as it is written..

Comment: This code is working fine for me. It is better to use 'switch' statement if you are having a number of conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the JavaScript code inside `script` tag and run the code after page is loaded so put inside **[`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)** callback, which fires at the end of the document loading process.

```html
<body>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      var randNumForQuote = Math.floor((Math.random() * 11));

      if (randNumForQuote == 0) {
        document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello";
      } else if (randNumForQuote == 1) {
        document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello1";
      } else if (randNumForQuote == 2) {
        document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello2";
      } else if (randNumForQuote == 3) {
        document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello3";
      } else if (randNumForQuote == 4) {
        document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello4";
      } else if (randNumForQuote == 5) {
        document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello5";
      } else if (randNumForQuote == 6) {
        document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello6";
      } else if (randNumForQuote == 7) {
        document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello7";
      } else if (randNumForQuote == 8) {
        document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello8";
      } else if (randNumForQuote == 9) {
        document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello9";
      } else if (randNumForQuote == 10) {
        document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello10";
      }
    }
  </script>

  <div id="quoteDiv"></div>
</body>
```

---

Although you ca reduce the code

```html
<body>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      var randNumForQuote = Math.floor((Math.random() * 11));
      document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello" + (randNumForQuote ? " " + randNumForQuote : '');
    }
  </script>

  <div id="quoteDiv"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank You so much @Pranav C Balan, that worked flawlessly

Comment: @TheEngineer : glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Javascript needs to be in a script tag if it's in html, and you need to have the div come before the script tag.

```html
<body>
  <div id="quoteDiv"></div>
<script>
  var randNumForQuote = Math.floor((Math.random() * 11));

  if (randNumForQuote == 0) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello";
  } else if (randNumForQuote == 1) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello1";
  } else if (randNumForQuote == 2) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello2";
  } else if (randNumForQuote == 3) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello3";
  } else if (randNumForQuote == 4) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello4";
  } else if (randNumForQuote == 5) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello5";
  } else if (randNumForQuote == 6) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello6";
  } else if (randNumForQuote == 7) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello7";
  } else if (randNumForQuote == 8) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello8";
  } else if (randNumForQuote == 9) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello9";
  } else if (randNumForQuote == 10) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello10";
  }
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body> 
    <div id="quoteDiv"></div>



</body>
<script>
// self executing function here

   var randNumForQuote = Math.floor((Math.random() * 11));

  if (randNumForQuote == 0) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello";
  } else if (randNumForQuote == 1) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello1";
  } else if (randNumForQuote == 2) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello2";
  } else if (randNumForQuote == 3) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello3";
  } else if (randNumForQuote == 4) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello4";
  } else if (randNumForQuote == 5) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello5";
  } else if (randNumForQuote == 6) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello6";
  } else if (randNumForQuote == 7) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello7";
  } else if (randNumForQuote == 8) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello8";
  } else if (randNumForQuote == 9) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello9";
  } else if (randNumForQuote == 10) {
    document.getElementById("quoteDiv").innerHTML = "Hello10";
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you put in a description (doesn't have to be long) of what the code does to fix the user's issue? :)